# Cannot load WFS via QGIS into PostGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql

I try to load this `WFS` https://fbinter.stadt-berlin.de/fb/wfs/data/senstadt/s_lor_plr_2021 into PostGIS using QGIS.
However, I always get the following error

> Error: 6
> Object writing error:
> Object create error: from #-9223372036854775808 to #-9223372036854775808. FError was: PostGIS-Error on adding attributes: FEHLER:  Geometry type (MultiPolygon) does not match column type (Polygon)

> Only 0 from 542 Objects written

[image: Screenshot import dialog]

Whats going wrong?

Comment: the column type of your table is`polygon` instead of `multipolygon`

Comment: @IanTurton but where do I set this? I have no table in `PostGIS` into which I import the `WFS`. The table is created upon import. I never set `polygon` anywhere...

Comment: you must have when you created the table

Comment: That tool implies the geometry type from the first feature it reads, which is not necessarily the case for all import features. Since now that table exists in the DB, `ALTER` its geometry type to `MULTIPOLYGON`, uncheck `Zieltabelle ersetzen` and reimport - and hope for the WFS not to serve even other types.

Comment: @geozelot Hm, I changed the type the following: `ALTER TABLE "fis:s_lor_plr_2021" ALTER COLUMN geom type geometry(MultiPolygon, 102689) using ST_Multi(geom);`. However, when I uncheck `Replace table if exists` I get the error `Relation »fis:s_lor_plr_2021« exists already`

Comment: @IanTurton No, the QGIS import tool does that. I created an empty database, connected via `QGIS` to that database, and then use the import tool (`database -> database management`) and then this (see screenshot) dialog appears. I add the layer, click import, and then the tool from `QGIS` creates the table in `postgis`.

Comment: It's supposed to append then...well, try Drag'n'Drop into PostGIS via the *Browser* panel, the underlying import engine usually does a pretty solid job. If that doesn't help you'd want to use an intermediate file storage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently there are mixed geometries in the Input Dataset. PostGIS does not like that (see Comments on my Questions)

They way I solved it now:
Since I opened the data in `QGIS` anyway, and it complained bout mixed `geometry types` I converted all the `geometries` to single `geometries`.

`Processing Tools -> Vector -> Multi- to Single Geometries`.

Since I know the data this is fine!